# Simulator and IRL iPhone not having the same behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, simulator

So, my converter app is finally working, but with one major problem. It's not working on the IRL iPhone, just the simulator iPhone. 
Like this (IRL iPhone):

[image: IRL Iphone]

And the simulator phone does the same thing like this:
[image: simulator iPhone]

IDK Why this one is so much smaller.

Only difference I can find is that my phone is in Norwegian, so the keyboard on there got a comma ',' instead of a period '.'

Code for the stuff that calculates it is here http://pastebin.com/nGaw7Agj

TLDR the irl iphone does not do the right thing, but the xcode simulator does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only difference I can find is that my phone is in Norwegian, so the keyboard on there got a comma ',' instead of a period '.'

That is the answer. Since you have different locale, the first one gets rounded off to 13, instead of 13.37. I don't know what quantities you are working with here, but in both cases, you seem to be multiplying with a constant ~133.4247, so the calculation is the same in both cases.

The problem is that you are not using `NSNumberFormatter` when reading the values from the strings. `NSNumberFormatter` will take care of locale for you. Using `[NSString floatValue]` is a very crude way of converting a string to a number, and you have no control over locale conversions.

In this line

```
float input = [inputText.text floatValue];
```

I would suggest changing to

```
NSNumberFormatter* fmt = [NSNumberFormatter new];
float input [fmt numberFromString:inputText.text].floatValue;
```

Comment: Ok. How do I fix this? Like, make the keyboard relaise thats its nothing but a english keyboard on all devices. Edit: Yes, but you can see that there is a .5 difference in the answer, which is too unprecise. I need it to be exactly the same on both.

Comment: "No visible @interface for 'Nsnubmerformatter'declares the selector 'localizedStringFromNumber:' ERROR.
fix?

Comment: The method is `[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber: numberStyle:]`, e.g. [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@"3,1415" numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

Comment: That seems complicated. Is there really no way to tell the keyboard itself to just learn how to use a period instead of commas in all languages?

Comment: I don't see how that adds to the complexity. My guess is that changing number format for your keyboard is going to be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Ok. So I should change the input from a float to a string, and then format the string?

Comment: Uhm, thanks for the help, but that kind of did not work. [ERRORS](http://i.imgur.com/NiYee.png)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18489/discussion-between-oscar-apeland-and-krumelur)